# Pegar o valor data attribute de um campo input file

Tags: javascript, ajax

estou precisando da ajuda com a seguinte situação

Tenho varios campos input files com o mesmo nome e que são usados para fazerem varios uploads de arquivos.

```
<form>
<label> Foto 3*4</label>
<input type="file" name="file[]" data-name="foto34">
<input type="submit">

<br/>

<label> Foto 16*9</label>
<input type="file" name="file[]" data-name="foto169">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

E gostaria de pegar os do data atributo para que eu possa identificar qual o nome do arquivo que esta sendo enviado por upload via ajax
Ja tentei pegar com

```
this.getAtributte("name")
ou
this.dataset.name
```

neste ultimo caso me retorna **undefined**.
A chamada ajax esta sendo feita assim:

```
  $(document).ready(function(e){
        $("#form").on('submit', function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'upload.php',
                data: new FormData(this), //PRECISO PASSAR o DATA_ATRIBUTTE AQUI
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData:false,
                success: function(msg){
                    $(".btn").removeAttr("disabled");
                }
            });
    });

});
```

Alguém saberia me auxiliar?

```js
$(document).ready(function(e){
   $("#form").on('submit', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var formulario = new FormData(this);

      var files = $(":file");
    console.log(files[0].value); 
    console.log(files[1].value);   
      // percorre os campos
      files.each(function(i, e){
         if($(e).val()){
 formulario.append('data-name'+i, $(e).data("name"));
}else{
 formulario.append(i, null);
}
      });

      $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: 'upload.php',
         data: formulario, 
         contentType: false,
         cache: false,
         processData:false,
         success: function(msg){
            $(".btn").removeAttr("disabled");
         }
      });
   });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <style>
    
input[type='file'] {
 display: none
}

    </style>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
 
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Foto 3x4</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Panel content
                    <br />
                    
                    <label for="file" class="bootstrap btn btn-info btn-xs" ><i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Selecionar Arquivo</label>
                            <input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" class="inputfile" data-name="foto34" >    
                            <button type="submit" class="bootstrap btn btn-primary btn-xs"> Enviar</button>
                            
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
           
  <div class="col-md-4">
   <div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading">
     <h3 class="panel-title">Foto 16x9</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
     Panel content
     <br />
     <label for="file" class="bootstrap btn btn-info btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Selecionar Arquivo</label>
      <input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" class="inputfile" data-name="foto169">    
      <button type="submit" class="bootstrap btn btn-primary btn-xs"> Enviar</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: se puder postar a função inteira de onde está tentando capturar essa informação

Comment: adicionado a duvida

Comment: Pegar o atributo **data-name** você diz?

Comment: Exatamente isso

Comment: Por que vc usa vários botões submit no mesmo form?

Comment: O correto é `this.dataset.name` mesmo, mas depende de onde vc está chamando isso, porque o valor de `this` pode mudar, por isso dá _undefined_.

Comment: Se vc está usando o `this `dentro dessa função de submit vai dar _undefined_ mesmo, pq o `this `faz referência ao `<form>`

Comment: @Sam pra cada input file, o cliente pode fazer o upload. Como os upload sao separados em card do bootstrap, ficou mais facil para o cliente entender que a cada upload ele deveria submeter o arquivo, poderia fazer o upload via javascript, assim que carregar o arquivo, mas nao consegui fazer dessa forma

Comment: Sei.. então você quer enviar todos os data de todos os campos file?

Comment: @Sam sim, isso mesmo essa esta sendo minha dificuldade, em mandar todos de forma identificada

Comment: Vc não pode fazer isso no PHP? Por exemplo, o primeiro campo file é o índice [0], logo no PHP vc sabe que a imagem no índice [0] é referente ao "foto34", assim como a do índice [1] é do "foto169".

Comment: Poderia, mas esses inputs de upload são montados dinamicamente conforme o perfil do usuario, logo não tenho uma referencia sobre a posicao de cada um, ou ate mesmo se ele vai existir. Daria pra inserir uma logica pra isso, mas pensei em fazer via Js mesmo

Comment: Talvez uma outra forma seria fazer varios forms para cada upload de documentos, mas pra mim isso seria muito ruim em termos praticos

Comment: @Sam alguma ideia de como poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Já já posto uma solução

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode percorrer os campos tipo `file` e adicionar ao `FormData()` uma array com os valores dos `data-name` usando `.append()`. É só atribuir o `FormData()` a uma variável e usar `.each` para ir adicionando os valores. Será criada uma array neste formado, na ordem dos índices dos campos `file`, começando em `0`:

```
Array
(
    [data-name0] => foto34
    [data-name1] => foto169
)
```

No PHP você irá pegar os arquivos normalmente com `$_FILES['file']`, já a array acima você irá pegar com `$_POST`.

O código do Ajax ficará assim:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
   $("#form").on('submit', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

      // atribui o FormData a uma variável
      var formulario = new FormData(this);

      // seleciona os campos tipo file
      var files = $(":file");

      // percorre os campos
      files.each(function(i, e){
         // adiciona os valores no FormData
         formulario.append('data-name'+i, $(e).data("name"));
      });

      $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: 'upload.php',
         data: formulario, //PRECISO PASSAR o DATA_ATRIBUTTE AQUI
         contentType: false,
         cache: false,
         processData:false,
         success: function(msg){
            $(".btn").removeAttr("disabled");
         }
      });
   });
});
```

Ou você nem precisa enviar um nome para os itens da array, bastaria enviar apenas o índice, assim:

```
formulario.append(i, $(e).data("name"));
```

Resultando assim no PHP:

```
Array
(
    [0] => foto34
    [1] => foto169
)
```

Pelo índice da array você saberá no PHP para qual file é associado, porque o `$_FILES['file']` também resulta numa array:

```
array(5) {
  ["name"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
    [1]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  ["type"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
    [1]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  ["tmp_name"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
    [1]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  ["error"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(4)
    [1]=>
    int(4)
  }
  ["size"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(0)
    [1]=>
    int(0)
  }
}
```

Comment: Muito bom @Sam vou fazer uns testes com seu codigo, valeu

Comment: Entendi, mas como faco o relacionamento entre eles? pq se for por posicao não daira certo, poderia apenas fazer o upload de um arquivo apenas e como saberia a qual foto ele pertenceria? Por exemplo, fazendo o upload apenas de foto169 o arquivo cairia no array de posicao zero, enquanto que a posicao zero em data-name0 equivale a foto34

Comment: Pode verificar se o campo file está com arquivo para fazer o .append

Comment: E como poderia fazer isso? Atraves do value? mas ao clicar em outro input mesmo sem arquivo no primeiro ele nao vai inserir o arquivo 2 na primeira posicao? Não entendi a logica Sam, poderia me dar um help? Veja como ficou a execucao.

Comment: Veja que quando o input está vazio, o índice da array `name` fica vazio, ou seja, sempre vai retornar uma array com o mesmo número de campos. No caso do append você pode fazer o mesmo. Veja se funciona assim: https://jsfiddle.net/erpqkyaf/

Comment: Infelizmente não, dessa forma [data-name0] sempre recebe o primeiro valor de data-name no caso foto34. Mas acho que o caminho é este, vou tentar achar uma solucao e encontrando eu posto aqui. Obrigado